# Is there a way to access spring boot's database from a static inner builder class/method for an entity?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, builder

Within Spring Boot, I have an entity class that I am currently constructing with a builder since it contains many parameters. I want to compute and store additional fields relevant to the entity on/before object construction, but computing these fields requires database queries. I can't access the database from a static context, and I'd like to avoid using some sort of non-static additional service to setup my entity objects (I'd like the computation and storage of these additional fields to be inseparable with entity creation).

It seems incorrect to auto-wire a repository into my entity class in any way. How do I go about implementing something like this, or is there a better way to architect my system to avoid this?